# Xamarin Studio using platform specific classes

Tags: c#, xamarin, portable-class-library, xamarin-studio

Hoi, i am using Xamarin Studio on OSX since one week and i have a problem with a PCLProject. How can i tell XS to use a specific class for each platform ?
e.g i have a class Connector.cs :IConnector in the PCL-Project but i want to use AndroidConnector.cs: IConnector in the .Droid Project and IOSConnector.cs : IConnector in the .iOS Project.
How can i tell this to Xamarin Studio to do so ? Is there a tutorial ?
The specific Class are not known in the PCL-Project so it doesent built.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Have a look at DependencyService.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xamarin.Forms, you can use the Dependency Service.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

> Xamarin.Forms allows developers to define behavior in platform-specific projects. DependencyService then finds the right platform implementation, allowing shared code to access the native functionality.

If you are using classic Xamarin, you can write a plugin to accomplish the same goals.

http://motzcod.es/post/104507063997/what-exactly-is-a-plugin-for-xamarin

This post specifically references nuget packages, but you don't have to use nuget. You can write your own "plugins" in your solution.